# Sencha Touch for Haxe FDT5?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, haxe, fdt

I'm trying to link to the sencha touch library from a FDT Haxe project. According to:

http://www.haxejs.org/externs/sencha-touch/

All you have to do is run from a command line:

haxelib install senchatouch

It installs sencha touch here : /usr/lib/haxe/lib/senchatouch/1,10

but my project doesn't know where to find it. How can I link my project to it? I also tried simply copying the entire senchatouch install into my project, but its very cumbersome of course and I get multiple compile errors. What is the correct way to do this? Thanks so much in advance.....

Here is a screen shot of the compiler errors:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to either:

1. Remap your $PATH variable of Haxe SDK to where FDT keeps the Haxe SDK.
2. Point FDT to the Haxe SDK with which you've installed the Haxelib into.

You'll also have to add the -lib argument to compile.hxml

### Remap $PATH

Remap is beyond the scope of this question but you get the idea.

## Using FDT's GUI

If using FDT's GUI, then go to Preferences>Haxe>Haxe SDK and point FDT to the Haxe SDK which you've installed Haxelib into.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow, nice comprehensive answer with screenshots. Thanks, I will give this a try...

Comment: IF it does let us know by accepting the answer, otherwise comment here again and I'll modify the answer.

Comment: Alan, That did work and thanks again for that. However as I mentioned in the latter part of my question, just like when I added the entire senchatouch library inside my project, I'm getting the same senchatouch compiler errors. I'll attach a screenshot . Let me know if I should start a separate stackoverflow thread...

Comment: Those errors are almost certianly associated with sencha touch and not the FDT setup. I can install other projects that use many haxelibs and they work fine (example this project with FDT: https://github.com/jamesbjackson/Demo ). Go onto the Haxe mailing list  here: http://goo.gl/EBj4C to ask for help on that.

Comment: For anyone wondering about the compiler errors:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/haxelang/VLqV-NIA__A/kqBaE9yQOcQJ